# Websitepanel: 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, web-publishing

I published an asp.net website to a webserver which can be managed through a control panel called websitepanel (websitepanel.net). I published the website through ftp to the web server.

**xyzwebsite.com** - this works! and shows Default.aspx page

**xyzwebsite.com/Default.aspx** and **xyzwebsite.com/Default** - Not working and shows the following but page actually exists and the directory also exists.

### [image: 404 error]

**The actual structure as seen in control panel of web server:**

---

### [image: The control panel files structure]

But in my local IIS it works fine. Do any of you have any insights about this because I am new to this kind of stuff's so any clue will be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the following attribute to the `<Modules>` tag in web.config and that solved my issue.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure, or have the hoster confirm, the Application Server windows features is installed on the remote server including the ASP.NET feature.

Answer (score 0):

One work around is to do a domain redirect as follows:

(you should use the pattern with regex)

```
 <rule name="Domain redirect" >
 <match url="*" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.+$" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydummysite.com/{R:0}" />
 </rule>
```

Good luck & hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1)  First thing is to verify is, your domain is correctly pointed to server where you have uploaded your website.

2) If you are able to browse Default.aspx page with just xyzwebsite.com then xyzwebsite.com/Default.aspx should not give any error.

3) To run xyzwebsite.com/Default, you will have to make folder "Default" as a virtual directory and set it's own default page. To achieve it, [this tutorial](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2545/How-to-add-virtual-directory-from-WebsitePanel-21.html) will help you.